# What doth I be?

Tags: riddle, poetry

Embraced by rock, then taken by the air

Born unto water, yet a friend of fire

Child of the gods of the sky

Who am I, who am I?

As mighty as the rock

As a fast as the wind

As wise as water

As impulsive as fire

Smoldering sky, and soggy soil

I kill with a keratin coil

Who I am, who am I?

One of soil, fire, sea, and sky?

For each of my words, tell me why!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps you are

> a dragon.

*Embraced by rock, then taken by the air

Born unto water, yet a friend of fire*

> Dragons are often shown as living in caves (embraced by rock); they fly (taken by the air); many culture's dragons, like the biblical "Leviathan", are sea creatures (born unto water); dragons in Western mythology are usually fire-breathing (a friend of fire).

*Child of the gods of the sky*

> Chinese dragons, in particular, are divine creatures, often particularly associated with gods of rain and thunder.

*As mighty as the rock

As a fast as the wind

As wise as water

As impulsive as fire*

> Dragons are generally depicted as mighty, fast, wise, and (sometimes) impulsive or at any rate quick to anger.

*Smoldering sky, and soggy soil

I kill with a keratin coil*

> Fire breathed down from above (smoldering sky); association with sea and caves (soggy soil); aside from their fiery breath, sharp teeth, and (in some cultures) magical powers, dragons are also typically shown as having sharp curved talons, which are presumably made of keratin. ("Coil" seems a bit of a stretch, though, so that's a weak point.)

Comment: Huh. I'm sure there used to be a comment here saying that I was almost right but was meant to identify a specific _type_ of \[ANSWER\]. I suspect (on little evidence) that doing so requires popular-culture knowledge I don't have, but I'm still curious. @RewanDemontay would you like to enlighten me? (Obviously it's fine if the answer is "no, I wouldn't".)

Comment: Yeah you're right. I deleted it. Sorry for the late reply. You merely misinterpreted part of (rock and water) the first two lines. If you can figure it then you'll find the right type of the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I'm here. (Sometimes. I do have a job, a family, etc.) I'm not sure what you were expecting, but unfortunately it turns out that merely knowing that I made a wrong guess at the intended interpretation of a couple of lines of a riddle doesn't instantly enable me to figure out what interpretation _was_ intended.

Comment: I understand. Well the wording of water is a metaphor for a substance-the word born is in there. And rock is another methphor for a substance, and it ties in.

Comment: Here was my original intention: _Baby_ dragon. Explanation to1. Embraced by rock-in an egg & 2. Born unto water-The amniotic fluid that comes with egg birth. Do keep your original analysis though.

Comment: Ah. I'm not altogether sure that works: some of the other lines seem to me to assume a full-grown dragon. "As mighty as the rock", "as wise as water", "I kill with a keratin coil" -- those all seem to me like things that a dragon has to grow into rather than being born with.

Comment: Well it was more what it would grow into, but I see your point.